# Custom column is not updating in customer_entity table

Tags: magento2, model

I added custom column 'email_status' in customer_entity table via dc_schema.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
        <table name="customer_entity">
            <column xsi:type="tinyint" name="email_status" default="0" unsigned="true" nullable="false"
                    comment="1 = pending | 2 = sent"/>
        </table>
    </schema>
```

> bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist
>
> bin/magento setup:upgrade command.

The field added successfully. But when I am trying to modify it via customer model, It is not modifying. Here is the code.

```
        $customer = $this->customer->load(2);
        $customer->setData('email_status', 1);
        try {
            $customer->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the columns in customer_entity table should an eav attribute of customer. So for adding any new column in customer_entity table, We must create an eav of the same name with the

> backend_type = static